# SQLAlchemy large inserts with relationships

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

Something I’m struggling with in SQLAlchemy.  Suppose I have two model models:

```
TextLocator
----------------
id (primary key)
docid
span_start
span_end
UNIQUE constraint docid, span_start, span_end

tags = relationship('Tag', back_populates='text_locator')

Tag
----------------
id
locator_id (Foreign Key text_locator.id)
tag_name

text_locator = relationship('TextLocator', back_populates='tags')
```

If I import a csv with a million rows and each rows is :
`docid, span_start, span_end, tag_name`

What’s the most efficient way for me in SQLA to insert this into the tag table?

The issue I’m facing is finding the TextLocator that needs to be created vs queried for.

If I was doing 1 row at a time I could do something like:

```py
text_locator_instance = (
session.query(TextLocator)
.filter(
and_(docid == <docid>. span_start == <span_start, span_end == <span_end>)).first()

if not text_locator_instance:
    text_locator_instance = TextLocator(docid=<docid>, span_start=<span_start>, span_end=<span_end>)

tag_instance = Tag(tag_name=<tag_name>)
tag_instance.text_locator = text_locator_instance
```

How would I do this at scale with 1 million rows?

If it were pure SQL, I’d insert the 1 million CSV into a temp table, JOIN to TextLocator to get the ids, insert into TextLocator where the join fails and then insert into Tags with the all the ids via JOIN.

Comment: Are the tables empty before export?

Comment: Before import? No, unfortunately not.  I ended up getting around this issue by just using CORE and not relying on the ORM.

Comment: Could you add some details? which database? Will import work with other workers at 1 moment?